# select and make new list with specific information

Tags: python, list

EDIT2: Nevermind this, someone pointed my error. Thanks

first of all, this is an example of results i have

```
(172, 'Nucleus')
(172, 'Nucleus')
(472, 'Cytoplasm')
(472, 'Cytoplasm')
(472, 'Nucleus')
```

what i`m trying to do is to match the first number (position 0) and then look if there is a part of the word "nucleus" (here, it would be "nuc") It can happens that in each number there is only word that has nucleus.

i'm trying to make 2 lists : the first list would be only the number containing only "nuc" word. the second list would be containing those with nuc and other things (like cytoplasm in my example)

That is only a little part of my result.

I don't have example of code, because i have really no clue how to include only one valor of my query in the list ( as on the example, i would enter the number 172 two time)  (oops i now have an example of code)

EDIT: oops wrote that before i wrote the code i tried...

right now, my code looks like that :

here is how i got my example a little bit higher

```
    def number1(self, position):
        self.position = position
        List = [self.name()]
        for item in List:
            for i in range(position, self.c.rowcount):  
                self.number(i)



def separate_list(self, list_signal):
        nuc_list = []
        not_nuc_list = []
        for i in list_signal:
            print(list_signal(i))
            if list_signal(i)(0) == list_signal(i+1)(0):
                if list_signal(i)(1) and list_signal(i+1)(1) == re.search("nuc"):
                    nuc_list.append(list_signal(i))
                else:not_nuc_list.append(list_signal(i))
        return nuc_list and not_nuc_list
dc = connection()

dc.separate_list(dc.number1(0))
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class vincent.py", line 91, in <module>
    dc.separate_list(dc.number1(0))
  File "class vincent.py", line 61, in separate_list
    for i in list_signal:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

i know this is not cute, i tried doing it the best way i can .. (new to python and programming in itself)

EDIT2: Nevermind this, someone pointed my error. Thanks

Comment: It is not exactly clear to me what you are trying to do. You have a list `['nuc']` and you want to filter the other list, consisting of tuples(?) based on whether or not `'nuc'` is a substring of the second element in the tuple?

Comment: well, the first line of code gives me the example (on the top) and with that, i'm trying to select the matching number with only 'nuc' part in the second element of the tuple and put that in the first list. Then, on the other list, i would put everything that contains 'nuc' AND the other things (example here is cytoplasm)

Comment: `dc.number1(0)` is not getting you anything. Try `print`ing it and mess with that until it gets you a list of some sort you can iterate though if that is your idea. It isnt very clear what you are trying to do in dc.number1

Comment: dc.number1(0) gives me all my signaltype of protein. what i'm trying to do is use my 'separate_list' on that.  and yeah i will try getting something with print .. good idea thanks

Answer (score 0):

A few things, if you are trying to get the index, position 0 of the list as you say, you would use `list_name[0]`,  if you are using position to sort, [use a different method](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Are `(172, 'Nucleus') ... (172, 'Nucleus')` tuples or are they lists of their own? List you can use index with the [0] method, tuple you can assign it to two variables to work with the data as `number, cell_type = (172, 'nucleus')`

Also, at the moment `dc.number1` doesn't return anything so it cant be used at input to another function. Add a return of some sort or change what you are using as the input to whatever self.number is modifying.

You may want to make a list of all your results, e.g. `[(172, 'Nucleus'), ...(172, 'Nucleus')]` then you can iterate through with

```
for item in results_list:
     for number, cell_type in item:
         print str(number), cell_type
#Should give you "172 Nucleus"
```

Comment: oh god i'm so bad. i'm using another function in this function, and not returning everything. Welp. Thanks !